# What is wrong with my project by arm-none-eabi-gcc on stm32?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, stm32

I just want to deal with stm32 programming in c by arm-none-eabi-gcc from scratch and just working by registers, not drivers!
so very simple piece of code to set PortC.8 to 1 and switch on LED on stm32f1 discovery board.
I am compiling by this script:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -T *.ld -o main.elf main.c system_*.c  *.s
```

and main.elf file has been made successfully... but not working!!! and LED is OFF.

files in the directory is :

```
core_cm3.c
core_cm3.h
main.c
main.elf
startup_stm32f100xb.s
STM32F100RBTx_FLASH.ld
stm32f10x.h
system_stm32f10x.c
system_stm32f10x.h
```

all files from STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0 folder downloaded from st official website.

main.c:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
void EnableClock(void);
void InitPort(void);
int main(void)
{
    EnableClock();
    InitPort();

}

void EnableClock(void)
{
    //Enable HSI
    RCC->CR |= (uint32_t)(0x00000001);  
    //APB2 Prescalar to 1(HCLK not devided)
    RCC->CFGR &= (uint32_t)(0xFFFFFF0F);
    //APB2 GPIOC Enable
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (uint32_t)(0x00000010);
}

void InitPort(void)
{
    //PORTC Bit 8 set as output max speed 2MHz GPIOC_CRH->Mode8
    //PORTC Bit 8 set as Push Pull
    GPIOC->CRH &= (uint32_t)(0x00000002);
    GPIOC->ODR |= (uint32_t)(0x00000100);
}
```

I don't know where is the problem.. anyone may help me??

Comment: isn't `ODR` register 16 bits wide?

Comment: @LPs : All STM32 peripheral registers are 32bit ,and 32bit aligned, in ODR the upper 16 bits are "reserved".

Comment: @Clifford: Some registers like ODR can be accessed with 16 bit accesses, though (similar for the BSRR).

Comment: usually the document that you can (or sometimes cant) access then using 8, 16 or 32 bit, in the case of the STM32s I have seen that you can always use a 32 bit access, although I have seen one/some of their peripherals that you have to access it using the right size to get a desired result (shifting out the spi).

Comment: @Olaf : 'Can' and 'Must' are not the same thing; LP seemed to be suggesting there was an error. If using a pointer offset, or array index to access adjacent registers, 32 bit access is simpler than only using even numbered offsets, and worrying about endianness. Either way, it is clearly documented as a 32 bit register.

Comment: @Clifford: ESL, but I'm well aware of the difference. The reference manual for the stm32f4xx sub-family clearly says the GPIO registers can be accesses with 8/16/32 bit accesses. Does that differ for  other stm32? Said that: The `struct` member if the ODR in the header is `uint32_t`, so accesses are 32 bit anyway and even if using a 16 bit mask, endianess does not matter for the operation (and the operation is done with 32 bits because that's what the `int` is on that platform).

Comment: @Olaf :   I think we are in violent agreement!  I made exactly that point - endianness is not a problem with 32 bit access whereas with 16 bit access you have to access the *correct* 16 bits (on the odd or even address).  The point stands that the answer to LPs comment is *"no - it is not 16 bits wide"* - that is all I was pointing out; I see no reason for debate or clarification - I think it is only serving to confuse, and becoming increasingly irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Clifford: I hate to say you are correct (nothing personal, I always hate to accept I ran into the wrong direction). To my defense: I also thought the ODR was declared `uint16_t` until I checked the header for my last comment. Somehow I did not make the connection with the exact comment by @LPs. Sorry for that, let's blame the full moon!

Answer (score 3):

Your `main()` terminates.  What happens next depends on what follows the `__main` call in startup_stm32f100xb.s; possinly a forced reset, or an endless loop (until watchdog reset, if enables).

In embedded systems it is not normal for `main()` to return.

The "`Enable HSI`" is perhaps unnecessary or even incorrect. The core clock is HSI by default - a clock must already have been established for the code to be executing at all, and enabling the HSI will either have no effect, or disable a previously established clock, the system clocking will have been set up in system_stm32f10x.c, and if you have specific clocking requirements, you need to modify that to suit your board and/or application.  Using the HSI directly allows 8MHz operation, feeding it to the PLL supports up-to 64MHz, and the chip will run at up-to 72MHz when the PLL is fed from an external 4-16MHz oscillator (HSE).

If you are not establishing the clock correctly in system_stm32f10x.c (or leaving it running HSI-direct), then it is possible that the execution is stalled in `SystemInit()` in system_stm32f10x.c waiting for PLL lock, or if you have it really wrong is not running at all.

To be working on any bare-metal processor at the board-bring-up level, you should ideally have a hardware debugger (JTAG/SWI) so you can use your tool-chain's debugger to determine exactly what your code is doing and where it is falling over.  You can at least determine whether it is even running as far as `main()` - there is a significant initialisation implemented by startup_stm32f100xb.s and system_stm32f10x.c before `main()` run.  The latter normally requires modification to suit your target.

Comment: I just need to dig in to arm more and more... so started to reading some books like "ARM System Developer's Guide". thanks for your answers and helps.

Comment: @peymankhalili :  Be aware that most of the things you are likely to be having issues with are not ARM specific.  For example, not returning from `main()` is a general practice, what happens before/after `main()` is tool-chain and/or application specific, although the CMSIS does provide a great deal of commonality across ARM Cortex-M parts, and correct clock initialisation and switching is chip specific - ARM does not define the clock hardware.

Comment: @peymankhalili : Also the ARM System Developer's Guide pre-dates ARM Cortex-M and is largely obsolete.  ST's STM32F1xx reference manual is more likely to be of use, plus content at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp and more specifically for your part:  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_00_en/index.html and http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example derived from one that blinks pc13 (untested at pc8, but worked at pc13, can test it if you have issues)

flash.s

```
@.cpu cortex-m0
@.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb


.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

blinker01.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define GPIOCBASE 0x40011000
#define RCCBASE   0x40021000

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(RCCBASE+0x18);
    ra|=1<<4; //enable port c
    PUT32(RCCBASE+0x18,ra);
    //config
    ra=GET32(GPIOCBASE+0x04);
    ra&=~(0xF<<0);   //PC8
    ra|= (0x1<<0);   //PC8
    PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x04,ra);
    while(1)
    {
        PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x10,1<<(8+0));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
        PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x10,1<<(8+16));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Makefile

```
ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi
#ARMGNU = arm-linux-gnueabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0
AOPS3 = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -march=armv6-m
COPS32 = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m

all : blinker01.bin

clean:
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list

flash.o : flash.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) flash.s -o flash.o

blinker01.o : blinker01.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.o

blinker01.bin : flash.ld flash.o blinker01.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.elf > blinker01.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.elf blinker01.bin -O binary
```

or

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -march=armv6-m -mthumb -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o blinker01.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D blinker01.elf > blinker01.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy blinker01.elf blinker01.bin -O binary
```

You dont need to mess with the clock initially it comes out of reset using the internal oscillator.  So unless you have your own firmware that sets it to something else you wont need to set it to HSI.  A clock init would be needed to change it to use an external clock and/or to use the PLL.

```
GPIOC->CRH &= (uint32_t)(0x00000002);
```

This changes the register from 0x44444444 to 0x44444444 (sorry see edit below). which is another way of saying you didnt do anything.  You want 0x44444442 for the 2mhz if you want to read-modify-write which is cleaner, but not necessary since we know the power on reset state you should do Like I did above read the value mask off the bits to zero then set the bits you want, the whole pattern.  Or you can just shove the 0x44444442 or 0x44444441 or 0x44444443.

had you done an or equal then it would have made 0x44444446 which is an open drain output.  So if there is a pull up then it would light the led perhaps, depends, but you would want to use open drain for sinking more than sourcing.  Which end of the led is the gpio pin connected to do you need to source it or sink it to turn it on?  You set the output to 1 to set the output high, which on open drain just means dont sink.  Although for an input setting odr pulls it high for input pull up/down, but as an open drain output not sure if setting odr pulls it up.  easier to try push-pull first and if you just want it on then BSRR makes it easy to set or reset an individual pin in the port rather than touching the whole port with odr.

> Open Drain Mode: A “0” in the Output register activates the N-MOS
>   while a “1” in the Output register leaves the port in Hi-Z. (the P-MOS
>   is never activated)

So first step change your code to set the port to a push-pull output, and then if you want to really be from scratch you can replace the rest of the code you borrowed and own all of it.  Dont have to use the put32/get32 assembly I use, I have many reasons and tons of experience but that is the beauty of bare metal, do your own thing, you can use the volatile pointer approach as well which is likely what the header files you linked do, and simplify the bootstrap.  If you make sure that your entry point function never exits and you dont rely on .data nor .bss then you can reduce your bootstrap to

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word main
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
hang: b hang
```

Or define a C function for the other vectors or a dumping ground for the unused ones.  Note that I didnt put all the vectors in the bootstrap, depends on the chip and core but could be hundreds of vectors (up to 128 or 256)

And match the amount of ram you have for the stack pointer initialization value (0x20001000 in the example above).

EDIT, actually, sorry 0x44444444&=0x00000002 = 0x00000000, which sets all the ports to analog inputs.  you want it to be 0x44444441 or 0x44444442 or 0x44444443

Comment: There is no need for assembly code at all. And using standard integers types over fixed-width types is bad coding style, even iff `int` has 32 bits on the architecture. Then: why not use pointers as specified by CMSIS, but use integers for the register address? The code is unnecessarily obfuscated and bloated for not allowing the compiler to e.g. inline the functions implemented in assembly language unnecessarily (if there were functions required at all) and using hand-crated macros instead of the hardware CMSIS headers is error-prone.

Comment: why do we keep having to have this debate?  have you seen the CMSIS code, and you are trying to make a case that they are not error prone?  I use code like the CMSIS code with interview candidates to see if they know enough to know what is wrong with that code and what the risks are.  I have seen compilers all too often produce the wrong instruction for the load/store, and abstracting the load/store makes it much easier and less risky to take the code from within the chip sim, to a foreign language interface to the chip sim, to baremetal on the chip to as needed a driver on an os or an app.

Comment: without a re-write, or with maximum code re-use.  the more external files you pull in and dont hand validate the more risk you are adding to the project.  Your boss wont care that it was some third party code (that you chose to not hand inspect) that caused the project to fail.  it was your responsibility

Comment: everyone handles prior failures their own way, some folks take the path of dont fall into traps, others build a tool box of how to get out of the trap fast once fallen in.  both ways have their pros and cons.  I choose the dont fall into traps path.

Comment: you have to build the vector table, the assembler is present and working and is a very easy way, or you could invent yet another tool to do what a bunch of .words in the already existing and working and debugged assembler would have done.  Talk about risk, why create and debug and train on another tool to replace an existing tool? it is not trivial getting the object file right for the linker for the vector table.

Comment: you can turn the PUT32/GET32 functions into pointers using inlined functions and an optimizer, but you cant turn the pointers into functions if you need to. Many times I have seen people (including myself until I stopped doing the pointer thing) have to go line by line through the code and replace the pointers with functions for various reasons.  Quite painful every time you watch someone have to do that.  Or have to re-write their code because they didnt plan ahead.

Comment: the unsigned int thing is the trap I take a risk on that i can easily get out of very fast, avoids any need for includes or at least includes the compiler has to go find in some other directory.

Comment: 1) Don't use broken compilers or broken code. 2) Check the headers. That's always a responsible programmer should do. 3) You prefer sprinkling magic numbers all over the code or define your own headers for thousands of registers? The headers are created automatically, more and more often directly from the HDL code of the chip-design (or some common description file). 4) `stdint.h` is a mndatory header of a compliant implementation, For ARM (and all other modern CPUs with 8 bits/byte) `uint32_t` etc have to exist (otherwise: see 1).

Comment: I'm not a noob either and I worked on various critical projects for decades now. Broken code is always a bad thing and not related to using CMSIS/vendor headers. But you use much more code, complicate things by your hand-crafted code, it is less self-documenting for not using fixed width types, etc. So in the sum, it is much more error-prone. And no, assembly functions will not be inlined by the **C** compiler (nor the linker with LTO, because the information is not available in the object files), there is no automatic verification of definition and declaration, etc.

Comment: Move on, the 1980ies are long gone (but the music still lives).